# How can you inject an asp.net mvc3 custom membership provider using Autofac?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, autofac

I have an MVC3 app using Autofac and a custom membership provider.

If I try and inject the provider using the ctor, I get an error: 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object.'

```
public class MyMemberShipProvider : MembershipProvider
    {

        IUserRepository userRepository;

  public MyMemberShipProvider(IUserRepository userRepository)
        {
            this.userRepository = userRepository;

        }
```

Comment: You could use my custom membership provider which takes care of the plumbing for you: http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/09/a-more-structured-membershipprovider/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can not inject into the in-built providers (Membership / Roles). 
You can use the MVC 3 DependencyResolver with Autofac.

A quick example...

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{
    var userRepo = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserRepository>();
    return userRepo.ValidateUser(username, password);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this then is the service locator anti pattern, see: http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/11/windsor-managed-membershipproviders.html

Comment: It is certainly an anti-pattern, but if your constraints are to make use of the existing ASP.NET Membership providers, then you faced with rewriting all of what Membership and/or Roles provides, or introduce this anti-pattern. Note, anti patterns are not do or die when the alternatives may be significant amount of work.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid resolving in application code (validate user, etc) as this is the service locator anti-pattern. You want to resolve only in your 'glue' code/low level code.

This below is for windsor, but the implementation can be easily adjusted. Here is one outlined for castle windsor, but the implementation should be similar. Its a bit cleaner as this resolves in the call to GetProvider - which is the 'glue' code here, thus avoiding the service locator anti-pattern usage in the actual membership functions (such as ValidateUser)

http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/11/windsor-managed-membershipproviders.html

Answer (score -1):

That´s because you should inject your userRepository as well. Something like:

```
protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterType<UserRepository>().As<IUserReposotory>();
    builder.RegisterType<MyMembershipProvider>();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that MVC3 supports dependency injection for membership providers?

Comment: No propably not. Neil has the answer above.

Comment: Built in providers such as @Neil mentions in his answer make use of ASP.NET to load in the membership provider as part of the page life cycle. This predates MVC[1-4] and also the introduction of an IoC container.